Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку открывалось другое окно?
Проблема заключается в том, что я не могу сделать так чтобы при нажатии на кнопку button_1 открывалось другое окно. 
Смотрел другие такие же вопросы, но так и не понял как это сделать.
Вот первый код:
# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'menu.ui'
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic6 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(parent=MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 270, 161, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bahnschrift SemiBold Condensed")
        font.setPointSize(28)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 80, 531, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bahnschrift SemiBold Condensed")
        font.setPointSize(36)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(parent=MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Начать"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Тренажёр по английскому языку"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())



Вот второй код:
# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'start.ui'
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic6 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(parent=MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 460, 341, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bahnschrift SemiBold Condensed")
        font.setPointSize(28)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.button.setFont(font)
        self.button.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.CursorShape.PointingHandCursor))
        self.button.setObjectName("button")
        self.text = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.text.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 70, 681, 91))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bahnschrift SemiBold Condensed")
        font.setPointSize(36)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.text.setFont(font)
        self.text.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LayoutDirection.LeftToRight)
        self.text.setObjectName("text")
        self.button_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.button_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(440, 460, 341, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bahnschrift SemiBold Condensed")
        font.setPointSize(28)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.button_2.setFont(font)
        self.button_2.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.CursorShape.PointingHandCursor))
        self.button_2.setObjectName("button_2")
        self.button_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.button_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 360, 341, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bahnschrift SemiBold Condensed")
        font.setPointSize(28)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.button_3.setFont(font)
        self.button_3.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.CursorShape.PointingHandCursor))
        self.button_3.setObjectName("button_3")
        self.button_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.button_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(440, 360, 341, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bahnschrift SemiBold Condensed")
        font.setPointSize(28)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.button_4.setFont(font)
        self.button_4.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.CursorShape.PointingHandCursor))
        self.button_4.setObjectName("button_4")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(parent=MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "text"))
        self.text.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "text"))
        self.button_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "text"))
        self.button_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "text"))
        self.button_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "text"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())



так у вас просто две заготовки для UI, вам нужно как минимум прописать какую-то логику на сигналы от кнопок. Главное, в этих двух файлах ничего не пишите больше, они только для UI.
Добавьте логику на сигналы, и если у вас что-то не получится, возвращайтесь с вопросом

Спасибо. Пошёл делать

Просите.Я просто только вчера начал изучать pyqt6  и ничего не понимаю

Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.
main.py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

from q1598479_2 import Ui_MainWindow as Ui_Window_2


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(parent=MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 270, 161, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bahnschrift SemiBold Condensed")
        font.setPointSize(25)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 80, 531, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bahnschrift SemiBold Condensed")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(parent=MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Начать"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Тренажёр по английскому языку"))


class Window_2(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Window_2):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked) 

    def on_clicked(self): 
        self.window_2 = Window_2()
        self.window_2.show()
        self.hide()
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

q1598479_2.py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(parent=MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 460, 341, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bahnschrift SemiBold Condensed")
        font.setPointSize(28)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.button.setFont(font)
        self.button.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.CursorShape.PointingHandCursor))
        self.button.setObjectName("button")
        self.text = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.text.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 70, 681, 91))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bahnschrift SemiBold Condensed")
        font.setPointSize(36)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.text.setFont(font)
        self.text.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LayoutDirection.LeftToRight)
        self.text.setObjectName("text")
        self.button_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.button_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(440, 460, 341, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bahnschrift SemiBold Condensed")
        font.setPointSize(28)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.button_2.setFont(font)
        self.button_2.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.CursorShape.PointingHandCursor))
        self.button_2.setObjectName("button_2")
        self.button_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.button_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 360, 341, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bahnschrift SemiBold Condensed")
        font.setPointSize(28)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.button_3.setFont(font)
        self.button_3.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.CursorShape.PointingHandCursor))
        self.button_3.setObjectName("button_3")
        self.button_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.button_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(440, 360, 341, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bahnschrift SemiBold Condensed")
        font.setPointSize(28)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.button_4.setFont(font)
        self.button_4.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.CursorShape.PointingHandCursor))
        self.button_4.setObjectName("button_4")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(parent=MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "text"))
        self.text.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "text"))
        self.button_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "text"))
        self.button_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "text"))
        self.button_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "text"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())




Спасибо большое!!! Всё работает!

@Matvej пожалуйста.  Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour
